# Click event on sort option doesn't work: Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

There is a sort option on the website which upon clicking presents options which i want to click on.
Using the click() event for that sort label, does nothing.

That highlighted part is the label which is clickable in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onAK0.png), though click event for the same doesn't work via script.
From that list, i want to click on Most listings option.

Code:

```java
WebElement op= driver.findElement(By.id("sortBy-label"));
op.click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why it is not working without looking into the application. I can come up with something with the shared HTML. Make sure you use explicit waits and wait for the search results to be displayed before clicking on the SORT OPTIONS. Why don't you try this?

```
    //wait for the search results. Use explicit waits and try this
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("SORT BY: MOST ACTIVE")).click();
            List<WebElement> lis=driver.findElement(By.id("sortBy-menu")).findElements(By.tagName("li"));
            for (WebElement li : lis) {
                if (li.getText().trim().equals("Most listings")) {
                    li.click();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks shank087, Turns out it was a slow network issue. When i tried the same code from home, it worked perfectly. When on VPN i am having issues and will need to put waits in place.
Thanks!